# Users with read rights are not able to insert data in my SharePoint hosted app's List

Tags: list, permissions, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have `SharePoint hosted app`. In that I have created an List and I am managing data of that list using a form which I have created in my app page.

When I am inserting data with the user who has full rights in their SharePoint site are able to insert data. But the users who have read role in their SharePoint site they are not able to insert data from my list. Though the list is in my `appweb` and I have given Manage permission to the list and tenant in my `AppManifest` file.

What other ways I can do?
Is this possible?
Is there any other way that I can give permission only to my list that any user can manage it?

Answer (score 1):

The permission of this user on the list you want to insert data into is inherited from the permission of the site. So, when the user have read role in their Sharepoint site then this user also have read role on the list. So, if you want this user can insert data to the list you have to give this user at least Edit permission on the SP site. 
P/S: The permission you set in AppManifest file is the highest permission level for this app. Then when your app is running, the permission of the context in this app just have the highest permission is the manage permission on the list you have set.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. Now I am trying to give permission to my list using javascript. If you know any process or any link that could help me...

Comment: Nice to help you, if you want to give a permission for a user or group in your list using javascript. You have to add this user or group in to the role is defined by default(or you can create your custom roles with your custom permission level). If you want your list have an unique permission, you should create a custom role for that. Here is a link you can refer to create a role, add a user/group to the role: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185014(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the replay. Write now m facing another issue in the creating role. I am posting new question. and will share u that link if you can solve that.

Comment: Hey Mike can you please check my new question? here's the link to the question : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89849/error-in-sharepoint-hosted-app-add-permission-level-to-the-list-programmaticall