# Error in SharePoint hosted app: Add permission level to the list programmatically

Tags: list, permissions, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am trying to add permission to the list which I have created in my app. I am trying to give current user some permission to add update delete items from my list. I have used one article from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247079.aspx) site. And my code is as bellow:

```
function execOperation() {
    debugger;
    context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
    var factory =
        new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(
            appweburl
        );
    context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
    appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, appweburl);
    var appContextSite2 = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);

    var siteColl = appContextSite2.get_site();
    hostweb = appContextSite2.get_web();
    context.load(hostweb);

    web = appContextSite.get_web();
    context.load(web);
    user = web.get_currentUser();
    context.load(user);
    que_list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("MyList1");
    context.load(que_list);
    que_list.breakRoleInheritance(true, true);

    var permissions = new SP.BasePermissions();
    permissions.set(SP.PermissionKind.viewListItems);
    permissions.set(SP.PermissionKind.addListItems);
    permissions.set(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems);
    permissions.set(SP.PermissionKind.deleteListItems);

    // Create a new role definition.
    var roleDefinitionCreationInfo = new SP.RoleDefinitionCreationInformation();
    roleDefinitionCreationInfo.set_name('Manage List Items');
    roleDefinitionCreationInfo.set_description('Allows a user to manage list items');
    roleDefinitionCreationInfo.set_basePermissions(permissions);
    var roleDefinition = web.get_roleDefinitions().add(roleDefinitionCreationInfo);

    web.breakRoleInheritance(true, false);
    // Create a new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.
    var newBindings = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(context);
    // Add the role to the collection.
    newBindings.add(roleDefinition);

    // Get the RoleAssignmentCollection for the target list.
    var assignments = que_list.get_roleAssignments();
    que_list.breakRoleInheritance(true, true);
    // Add the user to the target list and assign the use to the new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.
    var roleAssignment = assignments.add(web.get_currentUser(), newBindings);

    context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
}
```

I have just copied the code from that article. But when I run my app it give me error :

```
You cannot customize permission levels in a web site with inherited permission levels
```

Any suggestions, What am I doing wrong?
Any help will be appreciated...!
Thank you in advance...!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the `breakRoleInheritance` method,

Replace the below code

```
web.breakRoleInheritance(true, false);
```

With

```
 web.breakRoleInheritance(true, true);
```

**Note:**

```
SPWeb.BreakRoleInheritance method (Boolean, Boolean)
```

Parameters,

**copyRoleAssignments** - true to specify role assignments are copied from the parent website to this website; false to specify only the current user is assigned to security roles.

**clearSubscopes** - true to specify unique role assignments are cleared from child objects and then inherit role assignments from this website; false to specify unique role assignments defined on child objects are left in place.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee547386.aspx)

Comment: I tried but getting the same error... :(

Answer (score -1):

```
web.RoleDefinitions.BreakInheritance(true, true);
web.Update();
```

if you target the roledefinitions instead of the spweb this will get rid the error message

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/71711)

Comment: if you target the roledefinitions instead of the spweb this will get rid the error message he is facing